# c# httpcontent - add Header If-Match errors

Tags: httpcontent

adding new header "If-Match"

```
 using (HttpContent content = new StringContent(serializedObject))
        {
            content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            content.Headers.Remove("If-Match");
            content.Headers.Add("If-Match", "XXXXXXXXXX");
        }
```

throws :

```
Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.
```

i can add any other headers fine

Comment: you're setting a response header, but using a request header reserved word?

Comment: the api im working with requires the If-Match to be put in the header for the PUT

Comment: ok, don't set it on the content tho, set it on the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited:

```
using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, new Uri(url))) {
    request.Headers.Remove("If-Match");
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-Match", "XXXXXXXXXX");
    using (HttpContent content = new StringContent(serializedObject))
    {
        content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
    // ...
}
```